# Flexible DateTime parsing on multi culture web application

Tags: c#, datetime

I have an ASP.NET web application which is multi culture meaning I have `en-us`, `en-ca`, `fr-ca`, etc.

My problem is when I am trying to Parse a date `1/22/2014` using `DateTime.Parse` and I am using `en-us`, it will work because the `ShortDatePattern` of `en-us` is `M/dd/yyyy` but if the user is `en-ca`, the `ShortDatePattern` is `dd/MM/yyyy`.

How can I parse the dates considering different cultures? I have tried the following codes:

```
DateTime.Parse(date);
DateTime.ParseExact(date, ShortDatePattern, Culture);
DateTime.TryParseExact(date, ShortDatePattern, Culture, DateTimeStyles.None, out date);
```

But still no luck for me.

**EDIT**

`DateTime.Parse` throws me an exception, string is not a valid datetime. Same with the `DateTime.ParseExact`. `DateTime.TryParseExact` give me a date of 1/1/0001.

Comment: "still no luck for me" doesn't say *anything* about what went wrong. Please be specific in terms of input and expected output. (Does it compile but throw an exception? Give the wrong value? Not compile at all?)

Answer (score 2):

If you're *absolutely sure* of the user's culture - and that they'll actually use that - you could use:

```
// I assume that Culture is a valid reference to a CultureInfo...
DateTime date = DateTime.Parse(date, Culture);
```

However, I'd strongly consider providing a calendar control or separate year/text-month/day fields on the page (with validation) so that what you post back to ASP.NET can be a machine-readable, culture-neutral date format, e.g. `yyyy-MM-dd`. Basically, turn the culture-sensitive representation into a culture-neutral representation as early as you can.

Answer (score 0):

If the user can choose multiple languages within your application, I would think it would be easier to cater for the multiple language choices.

Here is what I did sometime ago:

```
DateTime dateValue = DateTime.Parse(dateVar.ToString());
string currentCulture = XmlLanguage.GetLanguage(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.IeftLanguageTag).ToString();
CultureInfo culture = new CultureInfo(currentCulture);

Console.WriteLine(dateValue.ToString("d", culture));
```

DateVar being the date value that you want to convert to new culture.

The above code makes use of the System.Windows.Markup namespace

Just change Console.WriteLine your preferred output display.